# how to split a set of strings with a certain numbers

Tags: perl

I have a data saved in .txt like the following

```
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
RNDDDDTSVCLGTRQCSWFAGCTNRTWNSSAVPLIGLPNTQDYKWVDRNSGLTWSGNDTCLYSCQNQTKGLLYQLFRNLFCSYGLTEAHGKWRCADASITNDKGHDGHRTPTWWLTGSNLTLSVNNSGLFFLCGNGVYKGFPPKWSGRCGLGYLVPSLTRYLTLNASQITNLRSFIHKVTPHR
>sp|P13674|P4HA1_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA1 PE=1 SV=2
VECCPNCRGTGMQIRIHQIGPGMVQQIQSVCMECQGHGERISPKDRCKSCNGRKIVREKKILEVHIDKGMKDGQKITFHGEGDQEPGLEPGDIIIVLDQKDHAVFTRRGEDLFMCMDIQLVEALCGFQKPISTLDNRTIVITSHPGQIVKHGDIKCVLNEGMPIYRRPYEKGRLIIEFKVNFPENGFLSPDKLSLLEKLLPERKEVEE
>sp|Q7Z4N8|P4HA3_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-3 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA3 PE=1 SV=1
MTEQMTLRGTLKGHNGWVTQIATTPQFPDMILSASRDKTIIMWKLTRDETNYGIPQRALRGHSHFVSDVVISSDGQFALSGSWDGTLRLWDLTTGTTTRRFVGHTKDVLSVAFSSDNRQIVSGSRDKTIKLWNTLGVCKYTVQDESHSEWVSCVRFSPNSSNPIIVSCGWDKLVKVWNLANCKLK
>sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
IQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQL
>sp|P10144|GRAB_HUMAN Granzyme B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=GZMB PE=1 SV=2
MQPILLLLAFLLLPRADAGEIIGGHEAKPHSRPYMAYLMIWDQKSLKRCGGFLIRDDFVLTAAHCWGSSINVTLGAHNIKEQEPTQQFIPVKRPIPHPAYNPKNFSNDIMLLQLERKAKRTRAVQPLRLPSNKAQVKPGQTCSVAGWGQTAPLGKHSHTLQEVKMTVQEDRKCES
>sp|Q9UHX1|PUF60_HUMAN Poly(U)-binding-splicing factor PUF60 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PUF60 PE=1 SV=1
MGKDYYQTLGLARGASDEEIKRAYRRQALRYHPDKNKEPGAEEKFKEIAEAYDVLSDPRKREIFDRYGEEGLKGSGPSGGSGGGANGTSFSYTFHGDPHAMFAEFFGGRNPFDTFFGQRNGEEGMDIDDPFSGFPMGMGGFTNVNFGRSRSAQEPARKKQDPPVTHDLRVSLEEIYSGCTKKMKISHK
>sp|Q06416|P5F1B_HUMAN Putative POU domain, class 5, transcription factor 1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=POU5F1B PE=5 SV=2
IVVKGHSTCLSEGALSPDGTVLATASHDGYVKFWQIYIEGQDEPRCLHEWKPHDGRPLSCLLFCDNHKKQDPDVPFWRFLITGADQNRELKMWCTVSWTCLQTIRFSPDIFSSVSVPPSLKVCLDLSAEYLILSDVQRKVLYVMELLQNQEEGHACFSSISEFLLTHPVLSFGIQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQLNPDVVAPLPTHTAHEDFTFGESRPELGSEGLGSAAHGSQPDLRRIVELPAPADFLSLSSETKPKLMTPDAFMTPSASLQQITASPSSSSSGSSSSSSSSSSSLTAVSAMSSTSAVDPSLTRPPEELTLSPKLQLDGSLTMSSSGSLQASPRGLLPGLLPAPADKLTPKGPGQVPTATSALSLELQEVEP
>sp|O14683|P5I11_HUMAN Tumor protein p53-inducible protein 11 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53I11 PE=1 SV=2
MIHNYMEHLERTKLHQLSGSDQLESTAHSRIRKERPISLGIFPLPAGDGLLTPDAQKGGETPGSEQWKFQELSQPRSHTSLKVSNSPEPQKAVEQEDELSDVSQGGSKATTPASTANSDVATIPTDTPLKEENEGFVKVTDAPNKSEISKHIEVQVAQETRNVSTGSAENEEKSEVQAIIESTPELDMDKDLSGYKGSSTPTKGIENKAFDRNTESLFEELSSAGSGLIGDVDEGADLLGMGREVENLILENTQLLETKNALNIVKNDLIAKVDELTCEKDVLQGELEAVKQAKLKLEEKNRELEEELRKARAEAEDARQKAKDDDDSDIPTAQRKRFTRVEMARVLMERNQYKERLMELQEAVRWTEMIRASRENPAMQEKKRSSIWQFFSRLFSSSSNTTKKPEPPVNLKYNAPTSHVTPSVK
```

I am trying to split each section to as many possible 10 regions as I can.

for example the rows that starts with > remain the same. it becomes like  this

```
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
RNDDDDTSVC
NDDDDTSVCL
DDDDTSVCLG
DDDTSVCLGT
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can split a string into substrings of length <= 10 using `my @sub_strings =  $str =~ /.{1,10}/g`. This will use length = 10 for the first sub strings, and the final substring is allowed to have length less than 10.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland would it be possible to give me more tips ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, it seems like you want the beginning of each successive 10-region to shift by one position. In that case you can use a `for` loop and the [substr](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) function:

```
my $DESIRED_LENGTH = 10;
while (<>) {
    chomp; # remove trailing newline
    if (m/^>/) {          # if line starts with '>'
        print "$_\n";     # just print it
    } else {
        my $i = 0;
        while ($i + $DESIRED_LENGTH <= length($_)) {
            print substr($_, $i, $DESIRED_LENGTH);
            print "\n";
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

If you save this code as `script.pl` and your datafile as `data.txt`, then running `perl script.pl data.txt` will pass your data to the file, using the Perl [angle operator](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/prog/ch02_11.htm).

Comment: should I add any package or something else ? how can I invoke the data there?

Comment: No other packages needed-- this sort of simple text processing is the core of Perl. I added an example of running the script to the answer. Check out the first link (to the docs) and the second link (to a book), they should make that sort of thing clear.

Comment: one more question and I accept and like your answer. Is there a way to add the `10` as a variable? for example if I want it to be 15 or 5 or whatever, I can set it like this e.g. `perl script.pl data.txt 5`  also what will happen at the end if the last part does not have 10 letters ? will I still have it or it goes until there is 10 letters ?

Comment: You can use the "Getopt::Std" package (https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html) to pass the `$DESIRED_LENGTH` as a command-line argument. But as this is written (see the condition in the `while` loop) the program never prints any part of length less than 10: neither the trailing 9, 8, 7, etc. characters on a line, nor any of lines whose length is less than 10. That was the way I understood your example.

Comment: I accepted your answer but would you add the Getopt::Std too? I appreciate it a lot . thanks

Comment: If you `use Getopt::Std;` and then `getopts('l:');`, you can set `$DESIRED_LENGTH = $opt_l;` Check out the Perl book at https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/prog/index.htm .

Comment: I did add what you said and I ran it like this `perl split_into10.pl data.txt 10` but I get the following error `Can't open 10: No such file or directory at split_into10.pl line 9, <> line 16.`

Comment: Getopt is for command line switches, so what you'd want is `script.pl -l 10 data.txt`.